# InfoPath Rule - only allow to check on check box

Tags: infopath

Per requirements I have to display choice field values in check boxes fashion. However, only one item needs to be check. Basically prevent multi-select and user must select 1 of the option. How would I go by setting this up?

Answer (score 1):

You can display in a new textfield:

> Please select only 1 option

For that to happen, you have to create a rule.

1. New Rule
2. Action
3. If "Value > 2"
4. Set "new textfield" to "Please select only 1 option.

Otherwise you can do the checkboxes seperatly and check if one of the other is selected. If so, then print the message, or disable the other options.

Maybe this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I had luck with the following solution:

1. I created 3 checkbox fields, named field x, y, and z.
2. I created an Action rule for field x, that when field y or field z is equal to TRUE, set field x's value to false.
3. I created an Action rule for field y, that when field x or field z is equal to TRUE, set field y's value to false.
4. I created an Action rule for field z, that when field x or field y is equal to TRUE, set field z's value to false.

This limits the users options to one checkbox selection at a time, in real-time, with this group of fields.